# Mongoid: how to query for all objects where value is nil?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

I'm having a difficult time doing something such as:

```
Something.where(:field => nil)
```

or

```
Something.where(:field => { '$eq' => nil })
```

What's the right way to handle this in Mongoid?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That's the right way to do it. To find cars whose engine is `nil`, for example, use:

```
# Cars that have a _nil_ engine.
Car.where(:engine => nil)
```

If you're trying to look for the *absence* of a field (rather than one that's set to `nil`), use the `$exists` predicate:

```
# Cars that lack an engine entirely.
Car.where(:engine.exists => false)
```

Note that setting a field `foo` to be `nil` and lacking a field named `foo` are two different things.

Comment: Also note that if :engine is an array of the form "[a, b, c, nil]", your where clause ":engine => nil" will match those rows.

Comment: For me whether or not `:engine` exists or is `nil`, the condition `where(engine: nil)` does match.