# How to find embedded documents with nil field values in Mongoid?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, orm, mongoid

Is there a way to find nil values inside the embedded documents in Mongoid?

Given I have these models:

```
class Record
  include Mongoid::Document

  embeds_many :locations
end

class Location
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :record

  field :special_id, type: String
end
```

I can find records given a specific `special_id` of location model

```
Record.where('locations.special_id' => '123')
```

But, if I wanted to get all records with nil `special_id` in locations, this works but returns all of the records.

```
Record.where('locations.special_id.eq' => nil)
```

This one returns 0 results:

```
Record.where('locations.special_id.exists' => false)
```

Thanks

Comment: maybe http://stackoverflow.com/a/8963075/1197775

Comment: @juanpastas That is if you don't have embedded documents. That will work if the `special_id` is a field of the `record` model.

Comment: What about `Record.where('locations.special_id' => nil)`?

Comment: @muistooshort Put it as an answer and I'll accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`embeds_many` just sets up an array of hashes inside MongoDB so the usual dot-notation should work:

```
Record.where('locations.special_id' => nil)
# ------------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ just the usual JavaScript-style path
```

The `.eq` and `.exists` notations are generally used as methods on *symbols* as short forms. For example:

```
where(:'locations.special_id'.ne => nil)
```

would be a shorthand for:

```
where('locations.special_id' => { :$ne => nil })
```

If you try to embed the operator in the field name string then MongoDB will just think you're trying to use another component in the path.